# How to Remove an Item from the Office Orb Menu in Outlook

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, outlook, outlook-2007

Folks,

I've been working on ribbon development in Office 2007, but I'm running into an issue that's driving me a bit nuts. I want to remove the "Permissions" option from the Orb menu of a new mail message in Outlook 2007. I am not having any luck. I'm using VS2008 and VSTO 3. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,

Rex

Answer (score 0):

ahh, it turns out I was modifying the XML in the wrong part of the schema. The correct modification would look something like:

```
<officeMenu>
    <splitButton idMso="PermissionRestrictMenu" visible="false"/>
  </officeMenu>
  <tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify for other readers, you cannot actually delete this feature as a menu option, as per the xml above you can set visible to false, and hide the command.